# Replace a section of 2D array with another 2D array just using python lists?

Tags: python, arrays

How can I slice a smaller array into an N x M array if I know the point of insertion?

ie,

```
# Larger array
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

# Smaller array
[1,2,3,4]
[5,6,7,8]

# Insert at [1,6] gives:
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,5,6,7,8]
```

And using just list comprehensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]
s = [[1,2,3,4],
[5,6,7,8]]
def insert(large, small, row, col):
    for i, r in enumerate(small):
        large[row + i][col:col + len(r)] = r
insert(l, s, 1, 6)
print(l)
```

This outputs:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, NumPy offers a generic solution for arbitrary coordinates:

```
i, j = (1, 6)

x[i:i+a.shape[0], j:j+a.shape[1]] = a

print(x)

array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
```